# Faster way to filter and counting rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with 300k rows. It contains data with genes for samples of animals. I have 43k animals, each has a 190-202 genes (they could be different e.g. one animal could have an AA1 gene, second could have not that one). 
Example data frame looks that:

```
Gene_Name   AnimalNumber   Allele1   Allele2
AA1          0001            B          B
DSD          0001            A          B
KAD334       0001            A          B
EE2          0001            A          A
AA1          0002            A          A
DSD          0002            A          A
EE2          0002            A          B
COPA         0002            B          B
```

What I need to do?

1. Need to count how many gene is appear in table. I just use `df[Gene_name].value_counts()` and it's ok.
2. Need to count how many genes appear in specific Alleles configurations. For example configurations could be only: AA, AB, BB.

And I think it's my weak point, coz I just put all SNP names to list, and create for loop like this:

```
  for i in range(len(genelist)):
    pick = len(df[df['Gene_Name']==genelist[i]].where(genotyp['Allele1'] == 'A' | genotyp['Allele2'] == A).dropna())
    listOfResults.append(pick)
```

And I run that loop three times. One for AA, one for BB, one for AB. It's works but it takes few hours :(
So how to do it by pandas without obvius loop? I mean faster...

```
Expect result:
Gene_Name     all      AA      AB      BB
AA1           3330     2230   1000     0
DSD           1000     870    100      30
...
etc.
```

I got 'all' column as I said. How to speed up collecting data for 2nd, 3rd and 4th.

I didn't find anything helpfull to my problem.

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: You could use df,groupby('Gene_Name')
next step - you can iterate through the groupby object:
`     for name, group in  df,groupby('Gene_Name'):`

Also, is better to give an example as code - then it is easier to show an example with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using groupby and apply:

```
df[(df['Allele1']=='A')|(df['Allele2']=='A')].groupby('Gene_Name').apply(len)
```

on the dataframe you show

```
Gene_Name
AA1       1
DSD       2
EE2       2
KAD334    1
dtype: int64
```

Edit: 
The above code simply groups all rows that have 'A' as Allele1 or Allele2 and counts the occurences. So

```
AA gets counted as A
AB gets counted as A
BB gets ignored
```

Using `&` instead of `|` should result in

```
AA getting counted
AB getting ignored
BB getting ignored
```

To get counts for all different combinations, you can group by the genes *and* alleles:

```
df.groupby(by=['Gene_Name', 'Allele1', 'Allele2']).apply(len)
```

I tested this on a synthetic dataset of 100k entries and it takes around a second.

Alternatively, `pd.crosstab`, as suggestedby @Mark Wang is also a great idea

Comment: @wraped one more question... I implement yours suggestion, and I got bad results. I got 33k for AB, 34k for BB and 27 for AA where all for that gene == 34+27. I got 34k+34k+27. I replace `|` to '&' and now I have a good results. Why? usually `|` works fine too

Comment: Think I misunderstood the original question. I added some explanation of my solution, as well as a better way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like crosstab

```
pd.crosstab(df['Gene_Name'], [df['Allele1'], df['Allele2']], margins=True)
```